# How might a hidden parameter be added to a program when there is no shell alias?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, python

py.test thinks there is an argument `-n` when there is none. What could be adding it? The program works as expected on OS X but not on Ubuntu 16.04.

I've checked a number of possibilities, aliases, tried zsh, sh, but no luck.

```
± /usr/local/bin/py.test
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: -n
  inifile: /home/ahundt/src/keras/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /home/ahundt/src/keras
-> [2]
± sh
$ /usr/local/bin/py.test
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: -n
  inifile: /home/ahundt/src/keras/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /home/ahundt/src/keras
$ /usr/local/bin/py.test tests/
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: -n tests/
  inifile: /home/ahundt/src/keras/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /home/ahundt/src/keras
$ exit
-> [2]
ahundt@femur|~/src/keras on tfrecord!?
± pip2 install --upgrade pytest
Collecting pytest
  Downloading pytest-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (186kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 6.4MB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pytest)
Requirement already up-to-date: py>=1.4.33 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pytest)
Installing collected packages: pytest
  Found existing installation: pytest 3.1.2
    Uninstalling pytest-3.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pytest-3.1.2
Successfully installed pytest-3.2.1
ahundt@femur|~/src/keras on tfrecord!?
Requirement already up-to-date: pytest in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pytest)
Requirement already up-to-date: py>=1.4.33 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pytest)
± pip3 install --upgrade --user pytest
Collecting pytest
  Using cached pytest-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools (from pytest)
  Using cached setuptools-36.2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting py>=1.4.33 (from pytest)
  Using cached py-1.4.34-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, py, pytest
Successfully installed py-1.4.34 pytest-3.2.1 setuptools-36.2.7
± py.test tests/
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: -n tests/
  inifile: /home/ahundt/src/keras/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /home/ahundt/src/keras
± type py.test
py.test is /usr/local/bin/py.test
py.test is /home/ahundt/.local/bin/py.test
ahundt@femur|~/src/keras on tfrecord!?
± type /home/ahundt/.local/bin/py.test
/home/ahundt/.local/bin/py.test is /home/ahundt/.local/bin/py.test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such an argument, namely in `pytest.ini`.

```
# Configuration of py.test
[pytest]
addopts=-v
        -n 2
        --durations=20
```

`pytest.ini` files store configuration for your pytest setup. So, instead of providing a lot of command line options, you can simply type `pytest` and all properties will be picked up (test coverage, linting etc.).

If you remove the `-n 2` line, tests will still run. Hope this helps.